# Python flask sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, flask

Long story short, making a small application using Flask to have a small database running. To get going I find a code example online, but it's not working when running the db.create_all() command in the terminal.

All i get is a bunch of messages lines and the error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

From google I get solutions like changing so the config has the pathway where i am storing the program to change it from 4 / to just 3 etc. None of these has worked.

````
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username```
````

Comment: According to the documentation at https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/ you need four leading slashes. But are you sure that your file should be in the root of the file system?

Comment: @Matthias as stated I have already tried 4 slashes and I have tried to put the file path there.  And well when I look at youtube and find a turorial it's more or less the same as they done.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for anyone else that has the same problem.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```